# "Завади" чи "перешкоди" в контексті радіоелектронної боротьби

Tags: синоніми, вибір-слова, вживання-слів

Яке слово слід використовувати в контексті [радіоелектронної боротьби](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0) для опису протидії противнику: *завади* чи *перешкоди*?

Наприклад: "станція *завад*" чи "станція *перешкод*"?

На практиці застосовуються обидва варіанти у довільній формі (тобто можна зустріти в одному реченні і *завади*, і *перешкоди*).

Деякий час мені здавалось, що *перешкоди* слід використовувати, коли йдеться про навмисні дії, а *завади* — ненавмисні, але я не знайшов цьому підтвердження.

Comment: СУМ-11 в радіотехнічному контексті згадує лише слово «поміхи». Яке, проте, позначене в ньому як рідковживане і є очевидним русизмом. Схоже, «завада» й «перешкода» на той час у подібному значенні ще не вживались.

Comment: Держспецзв’язку - Державна служба спеціального зв'язку та захисту інформації України (https://www.cip.gov.ua) є регулятором національних стандартів щодо радіообладнання і водночас контролюючим органом.

Comment: Аналіз документів з офіційного порталу показує, що найчастіше терміни вживаються в контексті "топографічні перешкоди" і "глушники радіозв’язку (станції завад)".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Згідно з [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereshkoda), ***перешкода***:

1. Те, що заважає руху.
2. *<sub>перен.</sub>* Те, що заважає будь-чому.

Згідно з [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27804&page=929), ***завада***:

> 1. Те саме, що перешкода.

<sub>Тобто:</sub>
            <sub>1.1. Те, що заважає руху.</sub>
            <sub>1.2. *<sub>перен.</sub>* Те, що заважає будь-чому.</sub>

> 2. *<sub>спец.</sub>* Стороння перешкода **у вигляді електричного коливання**, яка заважає правильному прийманню сигналів.

<sub>Виділення «у вигляді електричного коливання» моє.</sub>

Звідси можна зробити висновки:

- В побутовому контексті «перешкода» та «завада» — повні синоніми. Слово «завада» наслідує всі значення слова «перешкода», причому переносне значення таким і лишається.
- В контексті радіоелектронних сигналів (який, я припускаю, можна поширити до сигналів узагалі) **спеціальний термін** «завада» має **вужче** значення: *перешкода* саме сторонніми електричними коливаннями (в загальному випадку — стороннім сигналом).

  Наприклад, залізна стіна, що не пропускає сигнал від передавача до приймача, не буде *завадою* (в спеціальному значенні).

  *Завади* бувають:

  - пасивні ненавмисні (шум з атмосфери (гроза), відлуння від рельєфу та стін і т.і.);
  - пасивні навмисні (зумисне використання відбивачів супротивником, наприклад, дипольних чи кутникових);
  - активні ненавмисні (випадкове використання сторонньої радіоелектронної апаратури поруч);
  - активні навмисні (зумисне використання радіоелектронної апаратури супротивником, як правило спеціальної).

  На жаль, перші видані томи СУМ-20 ще не мають статті «перешкода», а СУМ-11 не описує спеціальних значень цих двох слів узагалі, тому не можу з повною впевненістю сказати, чи має «перешкода» якесь спеціальне значення, як термін, в контексті радіоелектронних сигналів.

  Але можу припустити, що **не має**. Тоді із загальних значень слова «перешкода» випливає:

  - *Перешкода в прямому сенсі* — лише то, що фізично не дає сигналу дійти до приймача (зменшуючи його абсолютну — а не відносно сторонніх сигналів — потужність). Але не, наприклад, *завада* (як спеціальний термін).
  - *Перешкода в переносному сенсі* — будь-що, що заважає прийняти й обробити корисний сигнал. В тому числі *перешкода в прямому сенсі* або *завада (в спеціальному значенні)*.

  [Перешкоди та завади в контексті радіоелектронних сигналів http://svgshare.com/i/qt.svg](http://svgur.com/s/qt)

  Звісно, «завада» ще має загальні побутові значення (повний синонім слова «перешкода»). Але навряд чи використання цього слова в контексті радіоелектронних сигналів у загальних значеннях буде прийнятним. (Оскільки там воно вже зарезервоване як спеціальний термін.)

Міжнародне (у вікі):

- [Електромагнітна завада](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0) = *рос.:* [электромагнитная помеха](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0) = *англ.:* [electromagnetic interference (EMI; radio-frequency interference, RFI)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) — термін.
- [Перешкода](//pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), перепона, [ускладнення](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), утруднення = *рос.:* [препятствие](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5), [препона](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), [затруднение](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) = *англ.:* [hindrance](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindrance), [obstacle](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obstacle), [impediment](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impediment) — просто загальні слова.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76007/discussion-on-answer-by-sasha------).

Answer (score 2):

перешкода - спеціально створена (станція перешкод).
завада - ненавмисна дія (випромінювання атмосфери).
придушення - це перед тим, як ріжете курку.
подавлення - результат дії перешкод.